# How to show admob at the top of screen?

Tags: android, webview, admob

I am trying to show webview of my own website, admob banner and progress bar.

In the below code, webview and progress bar, admob banner everything is working correctly. But, admob banner is showing at the bottom.

How can I show the admob banner at the top of screen?
I have tried to move the adview to the bottom, but it is showing blank screen.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/lib/com.google.ads"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
   android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:background="@color/white"
    android:orientation="vertical" 
    tools:context="com.myapp.MainActivity">

    <com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView
            xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
            android:id="@+id/adView"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
            ads:adSize="SMART_BANNER"
            ads:adUnitId="ca-app-pub-3940256099942544/6300978111">
        </com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView>

<LinearLayout
        android:layout_above="@id/adView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

<RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

    <WebView
        android:id="@+id/activity_main_webview"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />
    <ProgressBar
    android:id="@+id/progress1" style="?android:attr/progressBarStyleLarge"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

</RelativeLayout>
</LinearLayout>    
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: In your "com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView" add this "android:layout_height="50dp".

Comment: And remove this line -    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"

Comment: Change  `android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"` to             `android:layout_alignParentTop="true"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<RelativeLayout 
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/lib/com.google.ads"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">
<com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView
 xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
 android:id="@+id/adView"
 android:layout_width="wrap_content"
 android:layout_height="wrap_content"
 android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
 ads:adSize="SMART_BANNER"
 ads:adUnitId="ca-app-pub-3940256099942544/6300978111">
 </com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView>

    <LinearLayout
    android:layout_below="@+id/adView"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >
     <RelativeLayout
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="match_parent"
      android:orientation="vertical" >
      <WebView
      android:id="@+id/activity_main_webview"
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="match_parent" />
      <ProgressBar
                    android:id="@+id/progress1" style="? 
      android:attr/progressBarStyleLarge"
                    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

        </RelativeLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: No, Use the above code  AdView show at the top of screen According to your Question

Comment: Thanks a lot. The code is working and showing the admob banner at the top.

Answer (score 1):

In Webview set bottom margin based on  your adview heights

```
   android:layout_marginBottom="50dp"
```

In AdView add

```
android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
```

Comment: I am using smart banner. so, I think I cannot guess the height of  admob. Is your code correct in case of smart banner?

Comment: that case use frame layout

Answer (score 0):

Inside

> com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView

Add `android:layout_alignParentTop="true"` and remove this - `android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"`

Comment: when I use this code, it is showing full page blank. and webview is not showing. may be admob takes time to load, but webview should load in a second.

Comment: It will take time to show admob. Check your logcat.

Comment: Add height to admob in xml like 50dp

Answer (score 0):

Change your parent `RelativeLayout` to `LinearLayout` and add this into the inner `LinearLayout`

```
android:layout_weight = "1"
android:layout_height = "0dp"
```

This will force your layout to stretch down to the bottom while taking up the remaining screen left by adView

Answer (score 0):

Use Constraint Layout

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/lib/com.google.ads"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.myapp.MainActivity">

    <com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:id="@+id/adView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        ads:adSize="SMART_BANNER"
        ads:adUnitId="ca-app-pub-3940256099942544/6300978111"/>

    <WebView
        android:id="@+id/activity_main_webview"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/adView"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"/>

    <ProgressBar
        android:id="@+id/progress1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/adView"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        style="?android:attr/progressBarStyleLarge"/>

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```